# plot two different contouf plot in the same figure MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot two different 3d data using contourf. I want them to be in the same figure. The problem is I cannot see the first data.

I am using hold on , but it doesn't fix the problem. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `contourf` plots a solid region of colour in a 2D plane. Another `contourf` plot will plot into the same 2D region. How do you expect to see the two different filled contour plots?

Answer (score 0):

David raises a good point. This is a completely filled plot stacked on top of another completely filled plot so you're going to have to go in and manually adjust the fill colors. While it can likely be done, I don't know off the top of my head how to do it and it seems like far more trouble than it's worth.

However, to answer the question, the generic method would be to stack the axes on top of one another. This can be expanded to as many axes as you want.

```
% Generate arbitrary data
test1 = peaks(20);
test2 = fliplr(flipud(test1));

hdl.mainwindow = figure;                      % Create our main figure
hdl.mainaxis = axes('Parent',hdl.mainwindow); % Create main axis in our figure window
hdl.subaxis1 = axes( ...
    'Parent',hdl.mainwindow, ...  % Create secondary axis in our figure window
    'Position',get(hdl.mainaxis,'Position'), ... % Stack on top of main axis
    'XAxisLocation','top', ...    % Switch axes locations for visibility
    'YAxisLocation','right', ...
    'Color','none' ...            % Turn off background
    );

hold all % Keeps axes from resetting, you'll have to manually adjust everything as needed
[~,hdl.maincontour]   = contourf(hdl.mainaxis,test1,10);
[~,hdl.secondcontour] = contourf(hdl.subaxis1,test2,10);
hold off
```

While it technically answers the question, you can see that it's not a very useful presentation of the data.

Perhaps a subplot?

```
% Generate arbitrary data
test1 = peaks(20);
test2 = rot90(flipud(test1),2);

hdl.mainwindow = figure;                               % Create our main figure
hdl.subplot1 = subplot(1,2,1,'Parent',hdl.mainwindow); % Create main axis in our figure window
hdl.subplot2 = subplot(1,2,2,'Parent',hdl.mainwindow); % Create main axis in our figure window

[~,hdl.maincontour]   = contourf(hdl.subplot1,test1,10);
[~,hdl.secondcontour] = contourf(hdl.subplot2,test2,10);
```